# Set intersection of dict values of type list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a "baseline" dict that has lists as values

```
baseline_dict = {"key_1": ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
                 "key_2": ["1", "2", "3"]}
```

Then every time I run my code I m getting a "new" dict, that has always the same keys as the baseline (produced by the same method, but on different input). The type of the value is also preserved. For example

```
new_dict = {"key_1": ["e"],
            "key_2": ["2", "3"]}
```

I would like to quickly identify if values of matching keys from `new_dict` "intersect" with `baseline_dict` and produce a `True` or `False` (`bool(set())` is `False`)

```
result = {"key_1": False, "key_2": True}
```

My current implementation involves looping over the `new_dict`, getting keys, extracting values and doing the `set().intersection` which works, but it is slow (many dicts to process) so I m a looking for a better approach.

Note: I cannot go away from having `list` as the value type

**Edit** my implementation

```
result = dict()
for new_key, new_value in baseline_dict.items():

    is_intersect = bool(set(new_value).intersection(set(baseline_dict.get(new_key))))
    result[new_key] = is_intersect
```

Comment: I don't understand what is the criteria exactly. You want to check that all values of the list in `new_dict` exist in the matching list of `base_dict`? Or is it enough if any value exists in `base_dict`?

Comment: you are right: any is good enough!

Comment: Unless you change the values in the dictionary themselves to sets I doubt you'll get any improvement. Creating the set from a list is still `O(n)` so the only real way to speed this up is by having the dict's values sets, and then the look-up will be cut down

Comment: That is interesting! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`isdisjoint`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.isdisjoint) method of `set` to determine if their intersection is null or not.

```
boolean_dict = {
    key: not set(baseline_dict[key]).isdisjoint(new_dict[key])
    for key in baseline_dict
}
```

---

***Note:*** `isdisjoint()` will accept any iterable as an argument.